# Debugging failed in Visual Studio Code for both (gdb) launch and (Windows) launch

Tags: json, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

When I am trying to debug my code by toggling breakpoints, the debugging gets failed for both (Windows) launch and (gdb) launch.

My *launch.json* code:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(Windows) Attach",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    },

    {
        "name": "(Windows) Launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Attach",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

### Problems faced while using (Windows) launch

When I toggle breakpoint and press F5 to start debugging, the following error in the **Debug Console** box appears:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the C/C++ Extension for Visual Studio Code
with Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac
software to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Loaded 'F:\Coding\C++\DS & Algo\a.exe'. 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. 
The program '[12340] a.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

When using (Windows) launch, an external terminal opens and prints the output of the whole code even some breakpoints are toggled.
I have no idea what is happening. How to debug correctly in Visual Studio Code and also provide the solutions for my above faced problems with (Windows) launch.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the **gdb** output box text.

Comment: Oh, yes. I was wrong. That is just an output, not an error. Edited my question just now.